# Extract data from Json return object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller I am calling a webservice

```
Metadata.Client.Service.Client returnClient = new Metadata.Client.Service.Client();

returnClient = client.UpdateClient(updateClient);

return Json(new { returnClient }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In my .cshtml Ajax call as below

```
 $.ajax(
 {
     type: "GET",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: '@Url.Action("UpdateRecord", "Client")',
     data: { "id": id, "name": clientName, "code": clientCode, "typeId": clientTypeId, "clientStatusCode": clientStatusCode },
     dataType: "json",
     beforeSend: function () {//alert(id);
     },
     error: function (request) {
     alert('error');    
     alert(request.responseText);
     },
     success: function (data) {
     alert('success');
     console.log(data);

     //var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
     //alert(parsed);
     //var k = JSON.stringify(data);
     //alert(parsed);

  }
```

I tried several ways to extract the data. In `console.log` it is showing as below

```
[09:27:07.989] ({returnClient:{ExtensionData:{}, ClientCode:"C09091", ClientId:39, ClientName:"Test1", ClientStatus:[{ExtensionData:{}, StatusCode:{ExtensionData:{}, Name:"Active", StatusCodeId:5}, StatusType:{ExtensionData:{}, Name:"OE", StatusTypeId:1}}], ClientType:{ExtensionData:{}, ClientTypeId:7, ClientTypeName:"FDFD"}}})
```

Please can anyone help out to extract this data

ie, `ClientName, ClientCode, ClientId, ClientStatus.StatusCode, ClientStatus.Name, ClientStatus.StatusCodeId, StatusType.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
success: function (data) {
    var ccode = data.returnClient.ClientCode;
    var cid = data.returnClient.ClientId;
    var cname = data.returnClient.ClientName;
    var ctypeid = data.returnClient.ClientType.ClientTypeId;
    var ctypename = data.returnClient.ClientType.ClientTypeName;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.returnClient.ClientStatus.length; i++) {
      var codeName = data.returnClient.ClientStatus[i].StatusCode.Name;
      var codeId = data.returnClient.ClientStatus[i].StatusCode.StatusCodeId;
      var typeName = data.returnClient.ClientStatus[i].StatusType.Name;
      var typeId = data.returnClient.ClientStatus[i].StatusType.StatusTypeId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to helps you. I forgot about one more way - you can also access items using 'dictionary-like' access: `data['returnClient'].ClientCode` or `data['returnClient']['ClientCode']`.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the great help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following :

```
var jsonData = eval("(" + data + ")");
```

This will return you the JSON object.Then you can retrieve your data from this JSON object either by using dot (.) operator or by using [ ]